# How to paste before the cursor after selecting a vertical block?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

I'm so sure that this must exist, but if it doesn't maybe there is a macro for it...

One of my most favourite features of vim is the insert before when in visual mode (`<C-v>`, select the lines, `<C-I>`, type a little, then <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

My issue is that I want to paste the clipboard contents before, not 'insert'. I tried `<C-P>` but no love.

I have read cheat sheets, searched everywhere, looked through the questions on here and haven't found it, but I could definitely be searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: Related: [How to paste a line in a vertical selection block?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4774/467) at Vim SE

Comment: Because there are no existing question for pasting before the cursor, searching for "vim paste before cursor" on both [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vim+paste+before+cursor&ia=qa), [bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=vim+paste+before+cursor) and [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vim%20paste%20before%20cursor) returns this as the top result, and it happens to have the answer to that question.

Comment: Note that: in this case, the clipboard content is 1 line long, and OP wants to paste the *same* content on *all* selected lines. That's what OP really want but not explained in the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I assume you mean using `I` in visual block mode to insert the same text on multiple lines, where hitting `p` simply pastes on the current line rather than all the selected lines.

In insert mode, you can hit `C-r` followed by a register to insert the contents of that register, so if you wanted to paste the unnamed buffer, you'd enter

```
C-r"
```

Similarly, to paste from the clipboard

```
C-r*
```

By entering insert as you normally would, then using `C-r`, you'll get the text on all of the selected lines.

Take a look at `:h registers` to see what registers are available to you.

Answer (score 178):

Generally, the <kbd>P</kbd> command (upper case, different from <kbd>p</kbd>) pastes the contents of the clipboard before the cursor position. Is that what you're looking for? (I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say you press Command+I, as my keyboard doesn't have a Command key.)

Comment: ok, sorry, <C-I> to do insert before. <C-P> pastes once only.

Comment: Well, this answer may not be what the original asker was looking for, but it seems to be the solution for everyone else.

Comment: They should have a rule that says "dismiss the rules about accepted answer if the non accepted answer has literally 10X the votes of the first, in a 3 digit number". Just turn it accepted or at least first to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

May seems late, but I faced the same problem.

e.g. A file having two lines:

foo
bar

1. Press v: visual mode
   select foo in virtual mode
2. Press y: copy
3. Move the cursor to "b"ar

4-1.
Press p => bfooar

4-2.
Press P(Shift+P) => foobar
Which is what I expected.

TLDR: Upper case P (shift + p)

Comment: simpler: with cursor in the line of foo, press: `gJ`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Alligator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465806/alligator) solution, using maps.

E.g. to paste the string `_s_` in 3 cases:

```
" |-- original --|-- pasted after C   --|-- pasted before C  --|-- pasted replacing C   --|
" |--------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
" |--          --|-- select column C  --|-- select column B  --|-- select column C      --|   --> step 0 (after copying/yanking a string) 
" |--          --|-- press <leader>py --|-- press <leader>py --|-- press p              --|   --> step 1 if yanked
" |--          --|-- press <leader>pc --|-- press <leader>pc --|-- press "+p            --|   --> step 1 if copied to clipboard
"       ABCD              ABC_s_D               AB_s_CD                 AB_s_D 
"       ABCD              ABC_s_D               AB_s_CD                 AB_s_D 
"       ABCD              ABC_s_D               AB_s_CD                 AB_s_D
```

Where the mappings for each register (yanked or copied respectively) are:

```
xnoremap <leader>py A<C-r>*<Esc>
xnoremap <leader>pc A<C-r>+<Esc>
```

In previous examples I pasted **after** column (even pasting before column C, I workaround to paste after column B). If desired to paste **before** just change `A` to `I` in the 2 mappings.

Instead of `"+p`, one could use plain `p` if previously: copied `+` to `*` register (needed in last case of table):

```
nnoremap <leader>z :let @*='<C-r>+'<CR>
```

Comment: With _copy_ I mean to clipboard (`+` register). Not the Vim `:copy` command. See [http://vimcasts.org/episodes/long-range-line-duplication/](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/long-range-line-duplication/)

Answer (score 0):

for example, we need insert **My** in 4 lines before word **Fish**:

```
def EatMyFish(x):
    return x - 1

a = EatFish(1)
b = EatFish(2)
c = EatFish(3)
d = EatFish(4)
```

1. copy **My** at `def EatMyFish(x):`
2. put cursor on **F** at line `EatMyFish(1)`
3. <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> vertical select
4. <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> select all **F** in column
5. <kbd>I</kbd> go edit mode for all 4 lines (it's big <kbd>i</kbd>)
6. <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> normal mode for one action (to remember: o = one or once)
7. <kbd>P</kbd> insert before cursor (it's big <kbd>p</kbd>, not small)

or

6. <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> to insert from register in insert mode, instead steps 6-7 above

anyway, now we have:

```
def EatMyFish(x):
    return x - 1

a = EatMyFish(1)
b = EatMyFish(2)
c = EatMyFish(3)
d = EatMyFish(4)
```